# Decrease size of turtle depending on len(word)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm having trouble with 2 parts of my code. Mainly that the text should decrease in size when the length is over 3 characters. I put:
if len(word) > 3:
`size = 10`
just not sure why it isn't working. Also, the colour doesn't change but the thickness does, why could that be?

```
print("Welcome to turtle word writer")
word = input("Write a word please: ")
word = word.upper()
selectedcolour = input("what color should you like it in? ")
thick = input("How thick would you like it(min:1 max:100): ")

import turtle
kurt = turtle.Turtle()
thickness = kurt.width
colour = kurt.color



colour(selectedcolour)
thickness(thick)

def A():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color("black")
  kurt.left(70)
  kurt.forward(100)
  kurt.right(140)
  kurt.forward(100)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.right(180)
  kurt.forward(40)
  kurt.left(70)
  kurt.pd()
  kurt.forward(40)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(40)
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(100)
  kurt.pd()


def B():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color()
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(95)
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.circle(-20,180)
  kurt.right(180)
  kurt.circle(-30,180)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.right(180)
  kurt.forward(100)
  kurt.pd()

def C():
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.forward(30)
  kurt.left(180)
  kurt.pd()
  kurt.circle(-45, 180)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.forward(90)
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.pd()

def D():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color()
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(95)
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.circle(-48,180)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(180)
  kurt.forward(100)
  kurt.pd()


def W():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color("black")
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(75)
  kurt.right(30)
  kurt.pd()
  kurt.forward(85)

def X():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color("black")
  kurt.left(55)
  kurt.forward(130)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(125)
  kurt.forward(75)
  kurt.left(125)
  kurt.pd()
  kurt.forward(130)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(50)
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.pd()
def Z():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color("black")
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(90)
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.pd()
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.right(120)
  kurt.forward(100)
  kurt.left(120)
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.pd()


def Y():
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.color("black")
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(60)
  kurt.left(40)
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.pu
  kurt.right(180)
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.left(95)
  kurt.forward(50)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.right(135)
  kurt.forward(95)
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(45)
  kurt.pd
def P():
  kurt.color("black")
  kurt.speed(1)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.forward(130)
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.pd()
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.fd(130)
  kurt.bk(100)
  kurt.fd(50)
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.circle(40,180)
  kurt.right(180)
  kurt.pu()
  kurt.forward(90)
  kurt.right(90)
  kurt.forward(130)
  kurt.left(90)
  kurt.pd()







draw = {"A":A, "B":B, "C":C, "D":D, "X":X, "Z":Z, "Y":Y, "P":P}
alphabet = ["A", "a", "B","b", "C", "c", "D", "d", "E", "e", "F", "f", "G", "g", "H", "h", "I", "i", "J", "j", "K", "k", "L", "l", "M", "m", "N", "n", "O", "o", "P", "p", "Q","q", "R", "r", "S", "s", "T", "t", "U", "u", "V", "v", "W", "w", "X", "x", "Y", "y", "Z", "z"]

for letter in word:
  if letter in draw.keys():
    if len(word) > 3:
      size = 10
    draw[letter]()
    print("There you go!")
  elif word not in alphabet:
    print("not a letter, try again")
    print("###################################")
    word2 = input("write a new word using letters of the alphabet, please: ")
    for letter in word2:
      if letter in draw.keys():
        draw[letter]()
    print("There you go!")
```

Comment: All your letter-drawing functions are hardcoding the coordinates (distances) the turtle is going (f.E. `kurt.forward(40)`). You'd probably have to multiply all of these by your `size` value by having them read a global variable or the like. Otherwise `size = 10` takes no effect - the turtle library can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Along with not doing anything with `size`, as @LMD notes (+1), you have lines in your code that at best do nothing, at worst cause an error:

```
thickness = kurt.width
colour = kurt.color
colour(selectedcolour)
thickness(thick)
kurt.pu
kurt.pd
```

What I would expect are:

```
kurt.width(thickness)
kurt.color(selectedcolour)
kurt.pu()
kurt.pd()
```

Since all but one of your distances and radii are divisible by 5, we'll make the two sizes `1` (small) and `5` (large) and pass them into the letter drawing code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def A(size):
    turtle.left(70)
    turtle.forward(20 * size)
    turtle.right(140)
    turtle.forward(20 * size)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(8 * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(70)
    turtle.forward(8 * size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(8 * size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def B(size):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(19 * size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.circle(-4 * size, 180)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.circle(-6 * size, 180)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(20 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def C(size):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(6 * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.circle(-9 * size, 180)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(18 * size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def D(size):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(19 * size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.circle(-9.6 * size, 180)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(20 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def W(size):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(15 * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.right(30)
    turtle.forward(17 * size)

def X(size):
    turtle.left(55)
    turtle.forward(26 * size)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.left(125)
    turtle.forward(15 * size)
    turtle.left(125)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(26 * size)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.left(50)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def Z(size):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(18 * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.right(120)
    turtle.forward(20 * size)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def Y(size):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(12 * size)
    turtle.left(40)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.left(95)
    turtle.forward(10 * size)
    turtle.right(135)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(19 * size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(9 * size)
    turtle.pendown()

def P(size):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(26 * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(26 * size)
    turtle.backward(10 * size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.circle(8 * size, 180)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(18 * size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(26 * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(90)

draw = {"A":A, "B":B, "C":C, "D":D, "X":X, "Z":Z, "Y":Y, "P":P}

print("Welcome to turtle word writer")

word = ""

while not word.isalpha():
    word = input("Write a word please: ")

word = word.upper()

selected_colour = input("What color would you like it in? ")
thick = int(input("How thick would you like it (min:1 max:100): "))

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('slowest')
turtle.color(selected_colour)
turtle.width(thick)

size = 5
if len(word) > 3:
    size = 1

for letter in word:
    if letter in draw:
        draw[letter](size)

print("There you go!")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Three or fewer letters:

[image]

Four or more letters:

[image]